# flutter Assists & Quick Fixes shortcut

Tags: dart, flutter

My IDE for Flutter is Intellij and I want to use the shortcut Assists & Quick Fixes. 
The shortcut was always **ALT+Enter**, but currently won't work anymore.

[image: shortcut]

Can anyone help me?
Thanks all! :)

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work?

Comment: What Flutter version are you using (`flutter --version`)?

Comment: Do you have the flutter sdk / dart support enabled?

Comment: @dazza5000 yes my dart support is enabled.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer
Flutter 0.10.1-pre.43 • channel master • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 4f4005ee65 (38 minutes ago) • 2018-10-15 12:18:13 -0700
Engine • revision 50c2e69daf
Tools • Dart 2.1.0-dev.7.0.flutter-b99bcfd309

Comment: @RémiRousselet It just doesn't pop up anything. I don't know if my keymap is correct or something else.

Comment: I had this as well recently and it started working again shortly afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure when search Dart Quick Assists

search configuration

[image]

Make sure these settings are enabled:

habilit configurations

[image]

I hope I've helped.